# Succeeded() function in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've seen several examples on the net that call a function called "succeeded". However, when I attempt to use said examples, I get an undeclared identifier error.

eg: `if Succeeded(SHGetFolderPath(...)) then ...`

Is there some package I need to include to use this function? Google has not been very helpful in finding an answer to this.

Comment: Did you try adding `ComObj` to the uses?

Comment: Sometimes, grep can succeed where Google fails. `grep -ri succeeded *`

Comment: Cool delphi feature: click menu Refactoring, click Use Unit.  Type Succeeded. It might locate the unit for you.  Cool delphi feature #2.  Click the mouse onto the Editor at the beginning of the word or function name or identifier, and hit F1 key on keyboard.  When the help contains a topic about that thing it will often also tell you where it is defined (what unit to add)

Comment: No. 2 might work for Jessica, but no. 1 is just for modern Delphi. Nice tips and I still have not tried Use Unit.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, if I port to a newer version of delphi that has better help files and has refactor features I will definitely be using those features!

Comment: @WarrenP, unfortunately, this feature is not always being Succeeded :-) Anyway, this function is merely a sugar for `ReturnValue = S_OK`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Succeeded` function is declared in both the `Windows` and `ActiveX` units. It doesn't much matter which you use, but if your program does not currently reference `ActiveX` then it makes more sense to use `Windows` in order to gain access to this function.